# PostgreSQL How to get a result, transactions via php

Tags: php, postgresql, phpunit

I need transaction for update, i do:

```
 $sql = 'BEGIN;SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL Serializable;
                UPDATE partner_statistic
                SET "views_count"="views_count"+1
                WHERE "id"=15
                RETURNING id;
            COMMIT;';
```

Transaction query success,but I use unit test, and not test this transaction But i don't get success result with pg_query, whow I can test ?

Comment: Do you need a transaction for a single statement?

Comment: Thank you, I sent a query the query executed successfully, but I can not get return success, no transaction can I get the result through fucntion  \pg_affected_rows, always objected to the average bank false

Answer (score 1):

do one call to pg_query per query.